# How to exclude a timestamp at interaction.plot?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to do a basic plot using `interaction.plot` to show the development of depression throughout an intervention.
In total I measured many other scales at 3 different time stamps (T0,T1 & T3). Depression was only measured at T0 & T2.
When plotting the other means of the other scales that were measured at the 3 timestamps everything works perfectly fine.
But when trying to plot Depression that was only measured at 2 timestamps the plot is completely empty.
I assume it's due to the not existing data of T1? As Time of Measurment and Group are the independent variables.

My code is the following:

```
interaction.plot(ZEITPUNKT,GRUPPE, CES)
```

before I used:

```
data$CES <- rowSums(data[c("CES2", "CES5", "CES7", "CES11", "CES17", "CES20", "CES1","CES3","CES4r","CES6","CES8r","CES9", "CES10","CES12r","CES13","CES14","CES15","CES16r" , "CES18" , "CES19")])
```

Is there a way to exclude the T1 timestamp in the code so the interaction.plot works?

Comment: Could you make a minimum reproducible example? I'm guessing that the "time" variable is a factor and you could just remove the `T1` level

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.